# How can I type a backtick (accent grave or "`") on a European (Dutch) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

How can I type a backtick (accent grave, or "`") on an European (Dutch) apple keyboard ?

Comment: Do you mean this character : ` ?

Comment: @Pierre W yes, that's backtick

Comment: On mine, this character is under de £, next to the <return> key. It's a Europeen azerty (French I guess). I'm sure it won't help you :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this image from [Apple's KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2841), it appears to be between the <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>.

[image: Dutch keyboard layout]

Answer (score -1):

On European keyboard, press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>.

Comment: What kind of European keyboard are you talking about?  The question is about the Dutch one, and the answer you gave seems totally wrong for that. You should delete it.